# How convert .webm to .mp4 using Java?

Tags: java, mp4, webm, video-conversion, jave

I would like to convert a video from .webm to .mp4. I have tried with Java library JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder). This is my code using Jave:

```
File source = new File("C:\\Development\\workspace\\java-project\\video.webm");
    File target = new File("C:\\Development\\workspace\\java-project\\video.mp4");

    Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
    AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
    audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
    audio.setBitRate(new Integer(64000));
    audio.setChannels(new Integer(1));
    audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(22050));
    VideoAttributes video = new VideoAttributes();
    video.setCodec("mpeg4");
    video.setBitRate(new Integer(160000));
    video.setFrameRate(new Integer(15));
    video.setSize(new VideoSize(400, 300));
    EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
    attrs.setFormat("mp4");
    attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
    attrs.setVideoAttributes(video);
    try {
        encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);
    } catch (EncoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This snippet work if i use like "source" a video .avi or .flv, but with a .webm nothing! What am i doing wrong? What could I do?

Comment: JAVE wraps ffmpeg.  Does your ffmpeg installation support WEBM files?

Comment: Did you try with `audio.setCodec(AudioAttributes.DIRECT_STREAM_COPY);`?

Comment: Yes, but also with this method (audio.setCodec(AudioAttributes.DIRECT_STREAM_COPY); ) i couldn't do it

Answer (score 2):

```
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
    import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaViewer;
    import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
    import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;


    public class XuggleApiTest {

         private static final String inputFilename = "filepath/filename.webm";
            private static final String outputFilename = "filepath/filename.mp4";
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                IMediaReader mediaReader = 
                       ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);
                IMediaWriter mediaWriter = 
                       ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename, mediaReader);
                mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter);
                IMediaViewer mediaViewer = ToolFactory.makeViewer(true);
                 mediaReader.addListener(mediaViewer);
                while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null) ;

            }
    }
```